# Lightning component button refresh

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component button that updates the status of a case when clicked in Lightning.  Is there a function that I can use to have the page refresh when clicked because as of now, I have to refresh the page manually to see the update?

Comment: Are you performing the update in Apex, with the Lightning Data Service, by redirecting through a Visualforce page...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();` to refresh View.

Here is documentation link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:refreshView/documentation